# Bash- getting week start from date

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to create a bash variable in a single line code that subtracts one day from current day and then get date of Monday of the subtracted day. How do I do this in a single line.

I tried:

```
date --date="1 days ago" -d "last monday"
```

But this option but this gets the last monday first and subtract one day. I want to subtract one day and then get last monday.

Comment: What have you tried?  SO is good for getting help fixing things, but isn't intended to be a script-writing service.  Also, have you looked at the `date` command?  The one from GNU at least is pretty fully featured and if you're just looking for the date of last Monday would make it pretty easy

Comment: date --date="1 days ago" -d "last monday" Tried this option but this gets the last monday first and subtract one day. I want to subtract one day and then get last monday

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
$ date -d "$(date -d yesterday +%u) days ago"
Mon Aug 21 18:18:54 PDT 2017
```

How it works:

- `date -d yesterday +%u` gets yesterday's day of the week (1=Monday, 7=Sunday).
- `date -d "$(date -d yesterday +%u) days ago"` returns the date for enough days ago to get the monday before yesterday.

  For example, since today is Sunday, yesterday's day of week is 6 (Saturday).  6 days ago is last monday.

  If today was Monday, yesterday's day of the week would be Sunday which is 7 and "7 days ago" would be the monday before today.